# munin mod_rewrite / to blank page

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, munin

I am trying to prevent users from accessing the home page of munin by redirecting it to an empty file

The issue is mod_rewrite here, I believe:

```
    # HTML
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/static
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .html$ [or]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =/
RewriteRule ^/(.*)          /opt/munin/www/cgi/munin-cgi-html/$1 [L]
```

I am not sure how to preven to root index.html from directing to /opt/munin/www/cgi/munin-cgi-html/ which is a perl script that is use for every index.html page.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to redirect every folder's root to the cgi script, except the web root and `static`? As well as every html file except in the root?

Try this, without any RewriteCond:

```
RewriteRule ^(?!static)([^./]+)/?$ /opt/munin/www/cgi/munin-cgi-html/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(?!static)[^./]+/([^.]+\.html)/?$ /opt/munin/www/cgi/munin-cgi-html/$1 [L]
```

This should be in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT` htaccess.